# Why doesn't hotfix password work?

Tags: windows-7, hotfix

I requested the hotfix downloads in this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970315 and Microsoft sent them to me with passwords, but they don't work.

Why and what can I do to change this?

I already googled for an answer, but I could not find a solution that would work for this case.

I tried downloading it again, but the same password was sent to me. I read someone saying that the password would expire after a week, but I tried it right away. Then someone said that we need to run the hotfix as admin and I did.

What else should I try?

I am using Windows 7. Thanks

Comment: Did you try contacting Microsoft support?  (FWIW I pulled down a passworded hotfix last week with no problem.)

Comment: Just asked the same question in the forums... Yes, this is weird :(

Comment: Have you tried reaching Microsoft support again? It may be an error on their part.

Comment: Usually this is becuase you are trying to type the password.  I have found copy and paste the most reliable

Comment: Request the download again, use a different email account.

Comment: I did copy and past. It doesn't work. I am downloading it from a different download account, but the password is the same... Probably it won't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to get a hotfix as well. MS posted the below:

https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=11335&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

that says they are having password issues and it should be resolved. However, I am still having the issue (kb973404) even after their notification it should be fixed.